# Pycharm terminal is pointing to the wrong git executable (MacOS)

Tags: git, macos, pycharm

I'm trying to use git in the Pycharm terminal, but when I type `which git`, I get `/usr/bin/git`, and when I try running git I get an error (including a stack trace):

```
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

However, in a normal Mac terminal, if I type `which git`, I get `/usr/local/bin/git`, and this executable runs correctly.

How can I get the Pycharm terminal to point to the correct git? I tried updating the `$PATH` and changing the path to the git executable in the Pycharm preferences (and restarting Pycharm after doing this) but none of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because you are missing to add the file extension of executable.

Change your shell path in PyCharm terminal settings. Settings are located at:

```
Settings > Tools > Terminal > Application settings > shell path
```

In MacOs find out corresponding shell or bash executable path. It should be in `/usr/local/bin/<executable(git or bash or sh) with its extension>`

For windows, extension is `.exe`:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe` or `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

**Reference**:

[image]

**P.S.** This terminal setting is specific to a project, and you might need to change the settings for every new project.